# Given $A$, find $2\times 2$ matrices $B$ and $C$ such that $AB = AC$ but $B \neq C$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve this for my linear algebra class. I am not looking for someone to solve it, but for some guidance on where I should start.

$A$ = $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\6 & 3\end{bmatrix}$

Any tips are appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: find a matrix $B$ such that $AB=0$ and then define $C:=\lambda B$ where $\lambda \neq 1$ is a real number.

Comment: Or simply $B\ne0$ and $C=0$.

Comment: @lhf yeah, I wanted to write $\lambda \neq 1$ but I wrote $\lambda \neq 0$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $A$ is singular. Find a nonzero vector $v$ such that $Av=0$. Take $B$ with both columns equal to $v$.